# Trying to import sklearn_extra keep getting errors

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn-extra
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn-extra which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-67d5b7c323c5> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel')
      2 get_ipython().system('pip install https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/scikit-learn-extra/archive/master.zip')
----> 3 from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn_extra'
```

```
from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids
```

Can't seem to find an answer maybe you guys can help

Comment: Which python version and pip version you are using??

Comment: The problem is obviously not in the `import` statement, since it certainly seems that the package fails to install. Please update your post with he installation details and issues, and the relevant tag (`pip` or `conda`?).